# Oxygen in the earth’s atmosphere

Tags: molecular-biology

If CO<sub>2</sub> only makes up about 0.04% of the earth’s atmosphere how do trees and organisms in the ocean produce oxygen to 10% of the earth’s atmosphere?

Comment: Short answer: They had a very long head start

Comment: Some places the atmospheric Oxygen is nearly 20 %.

Answer (score 1):

### A very long head start

To elaborate on Drake Johnson’s comment, CO<sub>2</sub> used to be much higher in concentration. During the Great Oxygenation event, when cyanobacteria (ancestors) began photosynthesizing, they converted much of the CO<sub>2</sub> into O<sub>2</sub>, driving CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations down as they drove O<sub>2</sub> up.

Comment: When was this and what temperature was the atmosphere in then? Good sources?